# replacing a null column with data from a different column in a different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I have two tables

```
100 HL Road Frame   HL Road Frame - Black, 58   FR-R92B-58  Black   1431.50 1059.31 Road Frames 183 NULL
101 HL Road Frame   HL Road Frame - Red, 58 FR-R92R-58  Red 1431.50 1059.31 Road Frames 183 NULL
102 Sport-100   Sport-100 Helmet, Red   HL-U509-R   Red 34.99   13.09   Helmets 112 NULL
103 Sport-100   Sport-100 Helmet, Black HL-U509 Black   34.99   13.09   Helmets 112 NULL
104 Mountain Bike Socks Mountain Bike Socks, M  SO-B909-M   White   9.50    3.40    Socks   132 NULL
```

and for categories :

```
╔═══════╦═══════════════════╗
║     1 ║ Bib-Shorts        ║
║     2 ║ Bike Racks        ║
║     3 ║ Bike Stands       ║
║     4 ║ Bottles and Cages ║
║     5 ║ Bottom Brackets   ║
╚═══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

I am trying to replace the null values in the first table and populate them with the category ID from the 2nd table and I thought an insert statement would work how ever its not doing what I thought it would as I thought I would.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTCATEGORY
(
    categoryID       INT IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT pk_PRODUCTCATEGORY_category_ID 
    PRIMARY KEY,
    categoryname     VARCHAR(50)
)
```

is the table

```
ALTER TABLE product
    ADD categoryID INT
INSERT INTO product
SELECT categoryID
FROM   PRODUCTCATEGORY
```

**The error I get which is Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. for doing an insert**

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: You need work a liltle more in your question because isnt 100% clear. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You also might want to google tutorials on the INSERT statement in SQL, as you do not seem to have the basics down yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is basically :

```
INSERT INTO product(id, short_name, long_name, model number, color, price,
          smaller_price, type_name, type_id, what_does_this_value_even_represent) VALUES
(1,'Bib-Shorts'), (2,'Bike Racks'), (3,'Bike Stands'), 
(4,'Bottles and Cages'), (5,'Bottom Brackets');
```

What SQL tells you is `Msg 213, What value am I supposed to use for your 8 other columns`.

Comment: I am trying to essentially replace the null values in product with the values from productcategory by using the categoryID in that table and replacing the null values in the other table with that value.  if that clarifies it at all

Comment: Then you don't want to `insert` *values*, you want to `update` *rows* and `SET` *values*. You should check Juan's answer which is valid assuming that he guessed your  structure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

after you alter the table you should do an `UPDATE`

```
 UPDATE product P
 SET P.categoryID = PC.categoryID 
 FROM PRODUCTCATEGORY PC
 WHERE P.ID = PC.ID
   AND P.categoryID  IS NULL
```